# Load testing Parity Node

Tags: web3js, parity

After I finished my single node PoA setup, I wanted to test how many TPS it can handle.

During the load testing, I noticed that the transactions have stopped mining.

Instead, I am getting "Transaction culled...." logs.

Any idea what's happening?

[image: Culled transactions log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a [bug](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/9909) in local transactions in parity,

To overcome it I have added this flag when running my node `--tx-queue-per-sender 100000`

Answer (score 0):

> Transaction didn't get into any block, but some other tx with the same nonce got.

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/master/miner/src/pool/local_transactions.rs#L35

Comment: But it has stopped mining further transactions also

Comment: The solution was to kill and rerun the node, but i don’t want this to happen on production